# I have a field date that is a varchar and i want to treat it as datetime so I can compare it to now()

Tags: c#, mysql

```
update borrowdetails 
set LM_Status = 'BORROWED' 
where LM_Status = 'D' and Borrow_DueDate <= now()
```

`Borrow_DueDate` is `Duedate` column but it is a `varchar` and I want to make treat it as date time..

Comment: Can you change the schema? That would be the best approach - make the column type reflect the data you're trying to store in it...

Answer (score 0):

```
update borrowdetails 
set LM_Status = 'BORROWED' 
where LM_Status = 'D' and str_to_date(Borrow_DueDate,'%Y-%m-%d') <= now()
```

And this will convert your column to Date

```
UPDATE `borrowdetails `
SET `Borrow_DueDate` = str_to_date( `Borrow_DueDate`, '%Y-%m-%d' )
```